# Next.js Lerna monrepo: Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx, lerna

I have added a next + typescript project to a lerna monorepo.

When I run `lerna build` it runs `tsc` in all my packages and `next build` in my UI package.

The `tsc` part works just fine:

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.18
$ lerna run build
lerna notice cli v4.0.0
lerna info Executing command in 6 packages: "yarn run build"
lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@xxx/config' in 1.1s:
$ tsc
lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@xxx/domain' in 1.2s:
$ tsc
lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@xxx/utils' in 1.2s:
$ tsc
lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@xxx/components' in 1.0s:
$ tsc
lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@xxx/pages' in 1.0s:
$ tsc
```

However, I get the following error:

```
lerna ERR! yarn run build exited 1 in '@xxx/ui'
lerna ERR! yarn run build stdout:
$ next build
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
lerna ERR! yarn run build stderr:
Failed to compile.

../xxx-pages/lib/blog/blog.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
currently no loaders are configured to process this file. 
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export var Blog = function (props) {
|     var data = props.data;
>     return (<Container>
|       <BlogPosts data={data}/>
|     </Container>);
```

It looks like `next build` is having a problem with JSX `<` in:

```
>     return (<Container>
```

My understanding is that this should work out of the box and I should not try to customise the babel config.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is partially solved by using `next-transpile-modules`:

```js
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json')

function getModules() {
  return Object.keys(dependencies || [])
               .filter(dependency => dependency.startsWith('@jsdayie/'));
}

const modules = getModules();

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(modules);

function getAliases(modulesArray) {
  modulesArray.reduce((prev, next) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      ...{
        [module]: require.resolve(next)
      }
    };
  }, {
    resolveSymlinks: false
  });
}

module.exports = withTM({
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      ...getAliases(modules)
    };
    return config;
  },
});
```

## UPDATE 2023:

Built-in module transpilation is supported as of the release of Nextjs 13.1:

```
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['some-package', ...getAliases(modules)],
};
```

You can read more [here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-1#built-in-module-transpilation-stable).